# CSS - Set <div>s with "position: absolute" not to overlap each other

Tags: css, select, html, absolute

I have a table with n columns. Each column has a predefined width, and inside each column **th**, there is a **div** containing the actual header text, and a **div** containint a dropdown menu.

This is a simplified structure of the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div>TEXT</div>
            <div><select>...</select></div>
        </th>
    <tr>
    ...
    ...
</table>
```

the predefined width for the column can cause the text to be splitted in more than one line. When this happens, obviously the elements inside the **th** rearrange their position, causing a misaligment for column's **select**..

What I need to do, is to find a way to have every **select** aligned to each other, possibly anchored to the bottom of the **th**.

http://jsfiddle.net/SezSZ/2/ <- Here I've made an example of what I'm working on.

The 2nd table shows the table without any style (Except for th width): notice the misalignment between the first and second **select**.

the 1st table, instead, has some styles applied. As you can see, the second column text is overlapped by the select.. I tryed to solve this problem playing with the "position" attribute.. How can I tell the text to take as much space as it needs, without knowing how many lines it will be splitted to?

Another (minor) thing: I'd like to set every **select** to take 100% width of his parent div, but (TABLE 1) the dropdown menu right side is overlapping the table border (1 or 2 px, while in TABLE 2 everything is ok)..

Thanks in advance for any help, I hope I was clear enough, best regards

Comment: Any particular reason for using tables? With <div> this can be easily achieved.

Comment: Hi Rohan, I need to use table and I can't change it's structure :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3y7J/10/) is what you're after, right? The whole trick is to use `vertical-align: middle` on the `th`.

Comment: uhm yeah, that's quite what I'm looking for, except for the text alignment, that I'd like to be centered in the "remaining free space", and not aligned at the bottom with the select. see here, 2nd table http://jsfiddle.net/v3y7J/11/ . thanks anyway for the suggestion!

Comment: The only non-javascript method is this: http://jsfiddle.net/3WgLK/4/ but it's quite inflexible. You could do a bit of JS and determine what the tallest title is and then adjust the top padding of the cell accordingly.